# random select modal dialog onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I'am trying to random select modal dialog and end after specific number of click.

I'am new at javascript and this is what i got so far.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random()*4+1);
function myclick(){

if (randomNumber == 1) {
    $("#q1").click();
}

if (randomNumber == 2) {
    $("#q2").click();
}

if (randomNumber == 3) {
    $("#q3").click();
}

if (randomNumber == 4) {
    $("#q4").click();
}
}
</script>

<body>
<a id="q1" href="#dialog1" name="modal" image=></a>
<a id="q2" href="#dialog2" name="modal" image=></a>
<a id="q3" href="#dialog3" name="modal" image=></a>
<a id="q4" href="#dialog4" name="modal" image=></a>
```

UPDATE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
thanks for the fast reply.

Iam sorry not included all the script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.1.8.2.js"></script>
<script>

var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*4+1);


function myclick(){
if (randomNumber == 1) {
    $("#q1").click()
}
else if (randomNumber == 2) {
    $("#q2").click()
}
else if (randomNumber == 3) {
    $("#q3").click()
}
else if (randomNumber == 4) {
    $("#q4").click()
}
}
</script>

<BODY>

<h3>Web Design Quiz</h3>
<form name="quiz">
<a id="q1" href="#dialog1" name="modal" image=></a>
<a id="q2" href="#dialog2" name="modal" image=></a>
<a id="q3" href="#dialog3" name="modal" image=></a>
<a id="q4" href="#dialog4" name="modal" image=></a>
<input type="button" src="img/info.png" onclick="myclick()"></input>
```

I removed close";" after "Round" and add "else if". i still can only open 1 dialog at a time. I would like to open all dialog by clicking the button and end with the last one. how to refresh my random number everytime a click the button?

Comment: Do you have a question or a specific problem?

Comment: I have question and problems :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, firstly I hope you are aware you are using JQuery and have therefore including the correct scripts. Something like:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

next for a list of issues:

- You don't close the random `Round` function
- Your random number is set as a global variable and will only be set once (and not changed), but maybe this is your desire. If you need it different each time you should consider moving it inside of the `myclick` function
- You don't appear to be calling the myclick function anywhere, but maybe this is done inline?
- Calling the JQuery `click` function is not ideal for simulating a click. It would be better to create a separate function that takes the selector id for the div that should be processed

**TIP**: You can do this kind of thing with less code by custom building the JQuery selector which will save you having all the if statements. Something like:

```
$("#q" + randomNumber).click();
```

Also, using multiple if statements like this should make use of the `else if` statement too, because in this instance only one if statement can ever be successful

Comment: How do i move the variable into the click function?

Comment: I figured out how to move the variable into the function, thank you very much. But now i want to loop true all the dialog by click and end with the last one. How to do this? i have a button on every dialog box.

Comment: @user1716268: You should use a callback function so you know when each dialog has been closed, and then you can show the next one. If this is meant to be a sort of paged wizard form then you could probably just use one dialog and show/hide each page element within that when the next button is clicked

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, is it possible for you to come with an example? I really try to google it, but can't find any example that i can understand.

Comment: How do your dialogs work? How are they shown? you need to handle the click event of your button in each dialog, and on that click show the next dialog. I dont even understand why you have the random number if you just want to show all dialogs in order. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: My dialog work like a slow showing popup window with a background mask. the reason i want to open in random order is because it is a quiz and so it is harder for the student to memorize it next time they take the quiz.

Comment: ok, well like I said you need to handle the click event of the button on the dialog in order to close one and show the next. Personally, doing a quiz type application I would just have one form/dialog that displays dynamic text as the question. Which would be best obtained using an ajax request to the server. I think you seem to be doing too much as you seem to be at begginer level - you need to learn basics with javascript/jquery first

Answer (score 1):

Try to generate the random value with this code:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1
```

You forgot to close the round block.